# Selenium can't locate iframe

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Selenium fails to locate the iframe by `ID` and `Name`.

This is for an automated checkout test on Shopify. The specific issue lies within the payment field. I found the ID and name of the `iframe`, which is `card-fields-number-b1kh6njydiv00000`.

iframe Image:

[image: iframe Image]

Text Field Image:

[image: Text Field Image]

Code trials:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("card-fields-number-b1kh6njydiv00000");
System.out.println("Found iframe");
```

The error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id card-fields-number-b1kh6njydiv00000
```

Comment: My guess is that the ID is changing... have you tried refreshing the page and checking the ID again? Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: is your iframe Name or ID dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use XPath for this I believe. You will need to find the IFrame IWebElement with XPath, and then pass the IWebElement into the SwitchTo().Frame()

```
var ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(id, 'card-fields-number')]"));

driver.switchTo().frame(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); before switchTo.frame ?

Maybe you aren't out of all the frames

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("card-fields-number-b1kh6njydiv00000");
System.out.println("Found iframe");
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Prints out the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the frame name or ID is dynamic each time.In that case use index to identify the frame.

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
  for(int i=0; i<=size; i++){
    driver.switchTo().frame(i); 
    //Do necessary operation here.
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
   }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As per the images you have shared the `<iframe>` is having dynamic attributes so to locate and switch to the desired `<iframe>` you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following solutions:

  - *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.card-fields-iframe[id^='card-fields-number-'][src*='shopifycs']")));
    ```
  - *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe' and starts-with(@id,'card-fields-number-')][contains(@src, 'shopifycs')]")));
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to look for keywords that are the exact same for different dynamic id's. In this case, it was "card-fields-name". I did this by using the XPath locator.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'card-fields-number')]")));
```