# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node (null) was not a DOM element when trying to locate card-fields-iframe by CssSelector

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate an iframe by partial id. For this method, I used:
 `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='card-fields-number']")));` I have also tried xpath.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'card-fields-number')]")));
```

However, I still receive this exception:

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node (null) was not a DOM element`

I found out that when I enable javascript for HtmlUnit, it is able to locate the frame, and switch to it. I would rather not enable javascript as it runs very slow for me, and adds unneeded delay.

iFrame HTML code:

```
<iframe class="card-fields-iframe" frameborder="0" id="card-fields-number-7pbvqg7azsf00000" name="card-fields-number-7pbvqg7azsf00000" scrolling="no" src="https://checkout.shopifycs.com/number?identifier=438599641d0ed8fe61c161d72e62b5f8&amp;location=https%3A%2F%2Fshopnicekicks.com%2F2192362%2Fcheckouts%2F438599641d0ed8fe61c161d72e62b5f8&amp;dir=ltr&amp;fonts[]=Lato" title="Field container for: Card number" style="height: 43px;"></iframe>
```

iFrame ID is dynamic, so that is why I resort to using partial ID.

Website link: https://shopnicekicks.com/checkout
You must fill everything out until you reach the last page, which is the credit card information page.

**Update**
The iFrame is inside of the parent frame. 
Parent Frame:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<script>!function(){var e=function(e){var t={exports:{}};return e.call(t.exports,t,t.exports),t.exports},t=function(){function e(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var i=t[n];i.enumerable=i.enumerable||!1,i.configurable=!0,&quot;value&quot;in i&amp;&amp;(i.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,i.key,i)}}return function(t,n,i){return n&amp;&amp;e(t.prototype,n),i&amp;&amp;e(t,i),t}}(),n=function(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError(&quot;Cannot call a class as a function&quot;)},i=function(e){return e&amp;&amp;e.__esModule?e:{&quot;default&quot;:e}},o=e(function(e,i){&quot;use strict&quot;;Object.defineProperty(i,&quot;__esModule&quot;,{value:!0});var o=function(){function e(){var t=this;n(this,e),this.calls=[],window.ga=function(){for(var e=arguments.length,n=Array(e),i=0;i<e;i++)n[i]=arguments[i];return t.gaCall(n)}}return t(e,[{key:&quot;gaCall&quot;,value:function(e){var t=this;this.calls.push(e),clearTimeout(this.timeout),this.timeout=setTimeout(function(){t.calls.length>0&amp;&amp;t.sendMessage()},0)}},{key:&quot;listen&quot;,value:function(){var e=this;window.addEventListener(&quot;message&quot;,function(t){return e.receiveMessage(t)},!1)}},{key:&quot;sendMessage&quot;,value:function(){window.parent.postMessage({type:&quot;analytics&quot;,calls:this.calls},this.origin),this.calls=[]}},{key:&quot;receiveMessage&quot;,value:function(e){if(e.source===window.parent&amp;&amp;&quot;checkout_context&quot;===e.data.type){this.origin=e.origin,window.Shopify=e.data.Shopify,window.__st=e.data.__st;try{window.additionalScripts()}catch(e){console.error(&quot;User script error: &quot;,e)}}}}]),e}();i[&quot;default&quot;]=o});e(function(){&quot;use strict&quot;;var e=i(o);!function(){(new e[&quot;default&quot;]).listen()}()})}(&quot;undefined&quot;!=typeof global?global:&quot;undefined&quot;!=typeof window&amp;&amp;window); window.additionalScripts = function () {};</script>" src="https://checkout.shopify.com/2192362/sandbox/google_analytics_iframe" onload="this.setAttribute('data-loaded', true)" sandbox="allow-scripts" id="google-analytics-sandbox" tabindex="-1" class="visually-hidden" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" data-loaded="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node (null) was not a DOM element
```

...implies that there was *no such element* found as the returned node was **null** or was not a DOM element.

This is still a open [issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/issues/32) with *htmlunit-driver* team.

However there are certain things which you need to take care as follows:

- First and foremost, all the modern browsers come with built-in support for JavaScript.
- [HtmlUnitDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver) is a *WebDriver* compatible driver for [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) headless browser. It has fairly good *JavaScript* support (which is constantly improving) and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating *Chrome*, *Firefox* or *Internet Explorer* depending on the configuration used. So ideally while working with *HtmlUnitDriver*, *JavaScript* must be enabled, else *HtmlUnitDriver* may not ne able to detect the *JavaScript* based elements.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [HtmlUnitDriver does not load javascript when navigating a page from an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724856/htmlunitdriver-does-not-load-javascript-when-navigating-a-page-from-an-url/53744963#53744963)
- The element seems to be a *credit card field* and historically *Credit Card Number*, etc resides within `<iframes>`.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [Unable to locate element of credit card number using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030701/unable-to-locate-element-of-credit-card-number-using-selenium-python/54039805#54039805)
- Whenever an `<iframe>` is in play **`src`** attribute of the `<iframe>` tag plays a vital role.

  - You can find a detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- As per best practices while switching `<iframe>` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired frame to be available and switch to it.

  - We have discussed this aspect in your previous question [Selenium can't locate iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576206/selenium-cant-locate-iframe)

So you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.card-fields-iframe[id^='card-fields-number-'][src*='shopifycs']")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe' and starts-with(@id,'card-fields-number-')][contains(@src, 'shopifycs')]")));
  ```

### Update

See the snapshot of the `CssSelector` which identifies the element perfecto as per the HTML you have provided:

[image: CssSelector]

Comment: Both CssSelector and xpath return this exception. `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available:`

Comment: @Jeff Check out the update to my answer and let me know your thoughts about it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, you said that javascript must be enabled, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without javascript being enabled. It works perfectly like you said when it is enabled.

Comment: @Jeff I have already provided the link to the related discussion about `HtmlUnitDriver does not load javascript when navigating a page from an url`

Answer (score 1):

Just try with frame indexing  "//iframe[index]", where index integer.

e.g. xpath : //iframe[1]

Frame id may change dynamically but in a few application structure remains same so indexing solves the problem.

Please let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: It finds an iframe, but is not able to identify the elements inside of it.

Comment: Then only way is to find number of frames present as stated by sameer arora. if its a practice website that you are automation or publicly available website then please share the link.

Comment: There are approximately 5 frames. However, it can only locate iframe[1]. The other frames print out `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate a node using //iframe[number]`

Answer (score 1):

As the iframe has tag `iframe`, you can switch to the iframe using the tagname like:
 `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));`
And if you want to again switch to the default content, then you can use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: It switches to an iframe, and then fails to locate any element inside of the iframe. It might be because there are multiple iframes.

Comment: Ok, so you need to find out how many frames are there and then you need to switch to the frames one by one and then you need to operate on the element.