# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element while trying to click on the button VISA through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can't click on this button to create a checkout on my bot.
I want to click the image to get another page.

```html
<label for="VISA" class="choiceLabel">
            
    <input type="radio" class="visuallyhidden" name="cardTypeRadio" id="VISA" value="VISA" title="VISA" onclick="validateAndSubmit('VISA');">
     <span class="imgElt xh-highlight" onclick="validateAndSubmit('VISA');">
               <img src="/static/2.15.0.1/images/type-carte/visa.png" alt="VISA" title="Visa">
             </span>
            <span class="txtElt">Visa</span>
          </label>
```

this is my code:

```html
try:
             check = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"VISA" )))
            
             print ("Page is ready!")
             visa = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("label[@class='choiceLabel'][4]")
             visa.click()


        except TimeoutException:
             print ("Loading took too much time!")
             return check
```

im getting this error:

```html
 File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/pietro/Documents/monitor/x/bot.py", line 48, in all
    visa = driver.find_element_by_xpath("label[@class='choiceLabel'][4]")
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: label[@class='choiceLabel'][4]
```

Comment: It looks like the xpath is not correct. How did you extract the xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *button to create a checkout on my bot* seems to be a **Credit Card** related field and historically *Credit Card* related fields resides within `<iframe>`.

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Unable to locate element of credit card number using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030701/unable-to-locate-element-of-credit-card-number-using-selenium-python/54039805#54039805)
- [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node (null) was not a DOM element when trying to locate card-fields-iframe by CssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613481/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-returned-node-null-was-not-a-dom-e/54616999#54616999)

So if the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following solutions:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_css_selector")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='VISA']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe_xpath")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='VISA']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The xPath you are searching for might look more like this:

```
//input[@name='cardTypeRadio' and @value='VISA']
```

If this doesn't give you the unique element we can refine it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `xpath` is  wrong.Try this below code.Hope this helps.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='cardTypeRadio']").click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='VISA']").click()
```

If the `webdriver` click do not work.Try JavaScript to click.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='cardTypeRadio']"))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='VISA']"))
```