# How to enter date in the credit card number field using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, credit-card

I am trying to make a script to automatically checkout on a Shopify site. When I try to fill in the field that is asking for the credit card, selenium is not allowing me to send in the keys into the field and is saying that the element is not interactable. I've already tried clicking it, but it's still not letting me enter in the information. Does anyone know what to do?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-card-field-placeholder="Card number"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-card-field-placeholder="Card number"]').send_keys("1234")
```

URL: https://feature.com/4089909/checkouts/2f7c52e34622f0f301c0d4b5720ad80e?previous_step=shipping_method&step=payment_method

is the link I am trying to test this out on

Comment: What locator you are using

Comment: Please add html dom

Comment: Sorry, this is my first coding project and I'm fairly new to coding, what exactly is html dom? I'm also using requests and json

Comment: When you right click mouse and select inspect you see a chrome debuger with html add the html infomration from which you got this locatror

Comment: Do you mean this?

https://imgur.com/a/VyQxbom

Comment: @Spoit open that tree and add the image

Comment: shows what is inside the div

Comment: This is inside the div
https://imgur.com/a/0AXUPkN

Comment: There are other child elements open everything

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/byLseky I think it has something to do with iframes

Comment: @Spolt As per your code trials I have changed the question heading from _Java_ to _Python_ and edited the relevant tags. Please ensure that the edits are as per your requirement. In case I'm missing something I'll revert back the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the page to provide the credit card details we need to move beyond the [CONTACT INFORMATION](https://feature.com/4089909/checkouts/0b32b28705dd988ce170c3b0c9a41fac) information page. Hence, couldn't access it directly.

Ideally *Creditcard Number* fields are with in an `<iframe>`. Hence to access the *Creditcard Number* field within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_css")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-card-field-placeholder='Card number']"))).send_keys("1234")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_xpath")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-card-field-placeholder='Card number']"))).send_keys("1234")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847390/7429447)

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to locate element of credit card number using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030701/unable-to-locate-element-of-credit-card-number-using-selenium-python/54039805#54039805)
- [NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element while trying to click on the button VISA through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970347/nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-element-while-trying-to-click/54971811#54971811)

Answer (score 0):

you should use element with input tag  or any interactable tag to use sendKeys

see if the parent div element has a child input tag element and find that element instead of div

Also there is iframe inside , so if the input tag is inisde iframe , then first find iframe element then use

```
driver.switch_To.frame(iframe)
```

and then find the input element

each iframe are isolated session , you cannot talk to other frame from one frame so if you want to access elements inside one frame you have to switch to that framefirst

and also once done switch back to main frame using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0Mvx4Vn

I tried this but it's giving me "The string is not a valid XPath expression."
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@required autocomplete="cc-number"]').send_keys("1234")

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="cc-number"]').send_keys("1234") or driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="number"]').send_keys("1234")

Comment: try this located required is not an attribute , its aproperty , automcomple or id could be used

Comment: Also see if there are more than one iframe , if more than one iframe you have uniquiely find the iframe and then switch to it

Comment: there will be many tags with iframe , tries to find using xpath or css and make sure the locator finds only one iframe which you are interessted in

Comment: driver.switch_to.default_content() to exit from the iframe else you cannot access other elements outsie the frame , use switch to frrame each time you want to interact with any element inside iframe

Comment: Hi Sorry, to bother again, I tried doing the same thing for the Name on card, but now it's giving me element not interactable again, do you know the reason why? https://imgur.com/a/R8mA7Mc

Comment: I tried using driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="name"]').send_keys("First Last")

Comment: did you switch to iframe first ? is the element visible in browser , is the field enabled try click() isntead fo sendkeys and use switchtoactive element if the cursor is on name field and then send keys to active element

Comment: Yeah I tried
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-card-field-placeholder="Name on card"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@autocomplete="cc-name"]').send_keys("First Last")

Comment: Click name on card after switching to iframe

Comment: I tried driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-card-field-placeholder="Name on card"]').click() and it just says unable to locate element

Comment: Add the html it doesn't have dig tag in the screen shot you added.,