# Which method should I use for selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions object when waiting for Ajax based card details to load?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, credit-card

I'm trying to spider a page for links with a specific CSS class with Selenium for Python 3. For some reason it just stops, when it should loop through again

```
def spider_me_links(driver, max_pages, links):

    page = 1  # NOTE: Change this to start with a different page.
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://www.example.com/home/?sort=title&p=" + str(page)
        driver.get(url)

        # Timeout after 2 seconds, and duration 5 seconds between polls.
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 5000)

        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'card-details')))

        # Obtain source text
        source_code = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'lxml')

        print("findAll:", len(soup.findAll('a', {'class' : 'card-details'}))) # returns 12 at every loop iteration.
        links += soup.findAll('a', {'class' : 'card-details'})

        page += 1
```

The two lines I think I have it wrong on are the following:

```
# Timeout after 2 seconds, and duration 5 seconds between polls.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 5000)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'card-details')))
```

Because during that point I'm waiting for content to be loaded dynamically with Ajax, and the content loads fine. If I don't use the function to load it and I don't run the above two lines, I'm able to grab the `<a>` tags, but if I put it in the loop it just gets stuck.

I looked at [the documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) for the `selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions` class (the `EC` object in my code above), and I'm fairly unsure about which method I should use to make sure the content has been loaded before scraping it with BS4.

Answer (score 1):

Usually *creditcard name*, *creditcard numbers* resides within `<frame>` / `<iframe>`

To focus on those elements, you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `ID`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe_id")))
    ```
  - Using `NAME`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"iframe_name")))
    ```
  - Using `CLASS_NAME`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME,"iframe_classname")))
    ```
  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_css")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_xpath")))
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Unable to locate element of credit card number using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030701/unable-to-locate-element-of-credit-card-number-using-selenium-python/54039805#54039805)
- [NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element while trying to click on the button VISA through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970347/nosuchelementexception-message-unable-to-locate-element-while-trying-to-click/54971811#54971811)

Comment: Thank you for your effort in answering this question; very often it is the fact that an `<iframe>` is being used; recently I used a non-selenium technique to paste lines of javascript code into the console of chrome, and found the issue was indeed that `<iframe>`s were being used, but it was not in this case.  I will tag the question with the iframe tag just because your answer is so comprehensive and I will likely need it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector "means" that you want to select *element with tag name `'card-details'`* while you need to select *element with `@class='card-details'`*

Try either

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.card-details')
```

or

```
(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-details')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-details')))
```

And it appears to have worked.