# Not able to locate element, not iframe or page load

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to automate the checkout process of a shopify checkout and selenium can't seem to find the elements necessary to complete the checkout. NOTE: This checkout is not in an iframe and i have done extensive research to make sure that the page is fully loaded, so this is not a duplicate question.

```
try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id('number')
    elem.send_keys('4342923222931029')
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find input with number id"
```

Here is what i am trying to access: [screenshot of the source code of the checkout code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WRjQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try the `#number` css or `//input[@id='number']` in the developer tool (if your are using chrome)? were you able to find the element  in chrome browser?

Comment: Here is the link with the options to find the elements in the browser (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909). By this way we can figure out whether the issue is with selenium or the identification itself.

Comment: @supputuri Thanks so much for your help, so it turns out that this is an iframe issue. I have now found the iframe, however i am now getting the following error when trying to locate the iframe by id: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame

Comment: @supputuri here is my code: driver.switch_to.frame('card-fields-number-3nk14ojvg9f00000')

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536851/is-there-a-way-to-search-webelement-on-a-main-window-first-if-not-found-then-s/55537186#comment97778812_55537186) to loop through all the available iframes to find out the element which frame have the element.

Comment: @supputuri Here is a post of my exact same issue, it seems they found a fix in java, don't know how to convert to python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576206/selenium-cant-locate-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code to switch to the correct frame.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(id, 'card-fields-number')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(ele);
```

For Java solution refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576206/selenium-cant-locate-iframe)